# Devo compactar arquivos para salvar no banco de dados?

Tags: banco-de-dados, arquivo, arquivo-zip

> Não quero levar em consideração se salvar arquivos no banco de dados é ou não uma boa prática.

Tendo em vista que muitos sistemas salvam os arquivos (imagens, pdf's, doc's, etc) no banco de dados, gostaria de saber se é uma boa prática compactar esses arquivos, zipando os mesmos, por exemplo.

O tamanho do banco pode ter grande influência no sistema, seja por limitações, gargalos de memória, etc. Com isso, compensa reduzir o tamanho dos arquivos tendo em vista que terá um trabalho de compactar sempre que for salvar o arquivo e descompactar sempre que for mostrar esse mesmo arquivo ao usuário?

Comment: Não entendi muito bem o que você quis dizer com "influência no sistema" e "gargalos de memória", até onde eu saiba o tamanho físico de records (linhas) no banco pouco importa perto da _quantidade_ de records/linhas, exceto caso você esteja fazendo algo como indexar eles ou caso esteja preocupado em exceder o limite permitido pelo seu RDBMS.

Comment: @BrunoRB Acho que não me expressei bem. O tamanho do banco pode influenciar no desenvolvimento e ferramentas que irão ser utilizadas para o desenvolvimento, assim como manutenções de bases caso haja algum problema. Hoje não não importamos muito com memória ao desenvolver pequenos sistemas, mas existem sistemas que existem vários problemas de sobrecarga de memória. Existem pessoas que nem sabem o que seria GC e para que serve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Tendo em vista que muitos sistemas salvam os arquivos (imagens, pdf's, doc's, etc) no banco de dados, gostaria de saber se é uma boa prática compactar esses arquivos, zipando os mesmos, por exemplo.

Sim, e bastante comum, aliás. Uma das mais famosas pra isso, aliás, [é a ZLib](https://github.com/madler/zlib).

> Compensa reduzir o tamanho dos arquivos tendo em vista que terá um trabalho de compactar sempre que for salvar o arquivo e descompactar sempre que for mostrar esse mesmo arquivo ao usuário?

A não ser que seu sistema seja de missão crítica, e milhares de requisições sejam feitas para baixar arquivos gigantescos (falo aqui de centenas de megabytes), vale a pena sim.

[Segundo o próprio autor da ZLib](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31889610/1314276) (veja também a pergunta feita), ainda há formas de acelerar compressão e descompressão usando métodos mais rápidos, mas com uma qualidade de compressão menor. Aí vale a pena você executar testes sobre as variadas bibliotecas de compressão e suas opções para determinar o que atende melhor à sua necessidade.

Comment: No final da ultima frase, seria "para determinar o que atende..." não?

Comment: @DiegoF Sim. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Depende da frequência com a qual você vai querer acessar estes arquivos. Se eles vão ficar lá mofando a maior parte do tempo, e assumindo que você não tem ou não pode arrumar mais espaço em disco, talvez valha a pena. Agora se você vai ficar acessando eles constantemente não é muito esperto ter que descomprimir a cada acesso, vai acabar degradando sua performance a troco de salvar memória física.

Uma resposta exata vai depender muito da sua situação, mas no geral eu não recomendaria, gasto com espaço em disco é na maioria dos casos muito menos relevante que gasto com processador/ram.